# Show All Available (In Scope) Variables in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, intellisense

I was happy to find that hitting control + space in Visual Studio 2010 while working on  a C++ project displays all local and member variables that are currently available to me at the point where my cursor is.  Thanks Microsoft.

HOWEVER, control + space also displays everything that is available in the global scope.  All functions, variables, macros, etc.  The list contains thousands of items.  It is simply not possible to easily see my current function's local variables and my current class's member variables.

Does anyone know a trick for doing this?  In other words, just displaying a list of local and member variables available at the cursor point?  (If not, I might start prefixing all my variables with "johnsVar" so I can zoom to them quickly on the list.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Microsoft's implementation of autocompletion is called [IntelliSense](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcw1s69b%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and although you are able to [turn off some of its features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ecfczya1%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), it is not possible to modifiy its behaviour.

**But**, you can download and install some add-in like **Visual Assist X** that will modify this behaviour.

Check out [this video](http://www.wholetomato.com/flash/demoLg/demoLg.html) ;)

Comment: Link is dead. And almost link-only answer. :((

Answer (score 1):

This is available natively in Visual Studio 2017.
Just click on this button to filter local variables.

[image]